# How can I implement a RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView's item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I should implement a `RecyclerView`, its item contains a `TextView` and another inner horizontal `RecyclerView`.

I started it considering that the inner `RecyclerView` likes any other `View`. The issue happened when I tried to pass the context to the `LinearLayoutManager()` and the `RecyclerView.setAdapter()`.

The issue is: ***I cannot pass the context***, because I'm trying to pass it inside the first `RecyclerView` adapter

I cannot pass the context and don't know if this way is the optimal or if it will work at the end.

Here's my code:

```java
public class TheFirstAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheFirstAdapter.TheFirstViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<FirstItemModel> firstItemModelList;
    private List<SecondItemModel> secondItemModelList;
    SecondItemModel secondItemModel;
    TheSecondAdapter theSecondAdapter;

    public TheFirstAdapter(Context context, List<FirstItemModel> firstItemModel) {
        this.context = context;
        this.firstItemModelList = firstItemModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TheFirstViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add_routine_list_item, parent,
                false);
        return new TheFirstAdapter.TheFirstViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TheFirstViewHolder holder, int position) {

//there is an error in this line:
////java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

//////the solution: secondItemModelList= new ArrayList<>(); 
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            secondItemModel = new AddRoutineRoutines("Morning", "#9697D6");
            secondItemModelList.add(secondItemModel);
        }

        FirstItemModel firstItemModel = firstItemModelList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(addRoutineItemModel.getFirstItemText());
        holder.theSecondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        TheSecondAdapter theSecondAdapter = new TheSecondAdapter(context, secondItemModelList);
        holder.theSecondRecyclerView.setAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (firstItemModelList == null) return 0;
        return firstItemModelList.size();
    }

    class TheFirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;
        RecyclerView theSecondRecyclerView;

        public TheFirstViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_item_text);
            theSecondRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.the_second_recycler_view);
        }
    }
}
```

***Edit1:***
I passed the context but still there a problem I showed above.

***Edit2:***
The problem was I didn't initialized the `secondItemModelList`.

****After discussions this code works:****

```java
public class TheFirstAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheFirstAdapter.TheFirstViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<FirstItemModel> firstItemModelList;
    private List<SecondItemModel> secondItemModelList;
    SecondItemModel secondItemModel;

    public TheFirstAdapter(Context context, List<FirstItemModel> firstItemModel) {
        this.context = context;
        this.firstItemModelList = firstItemModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TheFirstViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add_routine_list_item, parent,
                false);
        return new TheFirstAdapter.TheFirstViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TheFirstViewHolder holder, int position) {

        FirstItemModel firstItemModel = firstItemModelList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(addRoutineItemModel.getFirstItemText());
        holder.updateView(secondItemModelList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (firstItemModelList == null) return 0;
        return firstItemModelList.size();
    }

    class TheFirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;
        RecyclerView theSecondRecyclerView;

        public TheFirstViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_item_text);
            theSecondRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.the_second_recycler_view);
        }

        public updateView(List<SecondItemModel> secondItemModelList) {
            secondItemModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                secondItemModel = new SecondItemModel("Morning", "#9697D6");
                secondItemModelList.add(secondItemModel);
            }

            TheSecondAdapter theSecondAdapter = new TheSecondAdapter(context, secondItemModelList);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            theSecondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            theSecondRecyclerView.setAdapter(theSecondAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `parse the context` do you mean **pass** the context? `The issue happened when I tried to parse the context` which issue?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes

Comment: that does not answer my question: `The issue happened when I tried to parse the context` which issue?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the issue is: ```I cannot pass the context```, because I'm trying to pass it inside the first ```RecyclerView``` adapter

Comment: please share your code

Comment: not quite clear what the problem is. RecyclerViews inside of a RecyclerView should not be any problem, i created a vertical list with recyclerView in which each row was a horizontal list (RecyclerView) of items. If passing the context is the problem, please show the code where you pass it and the error that happends when you do.

Comment: why can't you pass the context?

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAnas brother and coder you need to give clear and concise information atleast

Comment: Please stop hiding the details. `//////////there is an error in this line` which error?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it's: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference```

Comment: `secondItemModelList` is null it says, you never initialize it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thanks alot! it works now, I initialized it inside ```onBindViewHolder()```. How can I make the inner recycler horizontal? and is this really a bad code?

Comment: yes, this is really a bad code. You can make it horizontal by using corresponding LayoutManager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you may look for nested recycler view here https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

Comment: @MohdFaizan It's ```Kotlin``` and I'm using ```java```

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks, I followed your instructions and it works, Is this still a bad code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the context which you send to arg of constructor `LinearLayoutManager`?
If I understand your issue. You are using context from parent. Please use `itemView.context`.

Update:

Your code is very bad.

1. Do not create adapter in the `bindView` method.
2. Do not set/remove data in the `bindView` method.
3. `BindView` only use for bind data for view. Only that.

ViewHolder should be like this:

```
class TheFirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;
        RecyclerView theSecondRecyclerView;
        TheFirstAdapter adapter;

        public TheFirstViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_item_text);
            theSecondRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.the_second_recycler_view);
        }

        public void updateView(....) {
           //create new adapter if need.
           //set data for adapter if need
           ...
        }
    }
```

`onBindViewHolder` should be like this: `holder.updateView(...)`

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAnas Your code is very bad. 
1. Do not create adapter in the `bindView` method.
2. Do not set/remove data in the `bindView` method.
3. `BindView` only use for bind data for view. Only that.

Comment: this does not answer the question. Please don;t use `answer` for comments.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Really? This issue by change adapter data in the `bindView` method and create new instance in there. Not only with context.

Comment: `I dont understand exactly your question.` you really don't. Don't try to answer before you are sure that you do.

Comment: Oh. Ok Thank @VladyslavMatviienko. I understand that. Let's me edit my answer

Comment: @PhanSinh thanks I followed your instructions and it works, Is this still a bad code?